# Issue on installing wine on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, 11.10, wine

I have installed `wine` on my `Ubuntu 11.10` using `apt-get install.`

In between installation, that process was stopped unfortunately. I don't know that whether wine is installed or not. But, it didn't work.

If i again try to install using the same `apt-get install` , it gives the following error.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Please help me to rectify it.

Thank you in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying installation either by synaptic or Software center or any other installation is going on. First stop/kill that process and try again.

There is no support available for Ubuntu 11.10 now. You can use 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You need Super User privilege in order to make any changes to your system in linux, you can only make changes to your home folder by default.

Try

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

and enter your password.

Also, Ubuntu 11.10 is no longer supported, so you will not get any updates for it from Ubuntu repositories, also it is slow and unstable when it comes to performance.

In my opinion get 12.04 LTS (5 years support) or 13.04 (9 months support but faster and more stable).

here's the link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Get 13.04 if you want latest softwares.

Choose 64 bit if you have 4GB or more RAM .